# Original Corinex powerline ethernet wall mount

Tags: networking, local-area-network, ethernet

I am re-purposing some old Corinex powerline ethernet wall mounts. They came with a setup cd with a wizard application for setting up the hardware, but the application doesn't seem to work on 64bit windows 7 (not surprised really - the plugs are from 2004).

Anyone remember how to configure these things without the software tool? I have no idea what there current configuration on the hardware is.

I plugged them into separate wall sockets (the link status led indicated a link between them) and tried generating traffic and then looking at my arp table to see if i could see stuff, but nothing came up. My networking skills are limited at best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I emailed Corinex, and after clarifying exactly which model I was talking about Corinex ignored all further emails from me.

So apparently according to Corinex's stellar support, the first generation Corinex powerline wall plugs are not worth supporting.

email exchange:

> > Hi,
>
> Any eta on solving the problem?
>
> The program complains that it cannot
>   locate the local adapter. I found an
>   old corinex support page that
>   mentioned improper install of WinPcap
>   could be the issue. I have tried on an
>   xp computer and windows 7. Still no
>   luck.
>
> Can I get access to the Mac OS x
>   version of the software?
>
> thanks
>
> - Hide quoted text - On Mon, May 30, 2011 at 7:58 PM, Michael 
>     wrote:
>
>   Hi,
>
> Here are all the descriptors i could
>   find!
>
> Stamped in plastic housing of unit
>   Corinex PowerNet Ethernet
>
> On sticker on packaging CXP-WME 1.6
>
> On sticker on housing serial: 00 0b xx
>   xx xx xx
>
> Thanks, Michael
>
> On Mon, May 30, 2011 at 5:59 PM,
>   Corinex Support
>    wrote: Hi
>   Mr.,
>
> Can you provide the exact model number
>   of your device?
>
> Thank you,
>
> Corinex Support Team
>
> -----Original Message----- From: Michael [mailto:Michael Sent:
>   May-28-11 5:56 PM To:
>   support@corinex.com Subject: corinex
>   website: Setup tool for original
>   powerline
>
> This is an enquiry e-mail via
>   http://www.corinex.com/ from: Michael
>
> Hi,
>
> I have 4 of the original powerline
>   wall mounts (earlier than the AV200).
>   The setup tool does not seem to
>   function on Windows 7. Is there a
>   version of the setup tool for Windows
>   that would work on Windows 7 or
>   alternatively for Mac OS X(I have a
>   few Mac OSx based computers accessible
>   as well).
>
> Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

How about installing Windows XP Mode on the Windows 7 workstation and running the software from there?

Answer (score 2):

You don't say what model you're talking about.  On their website, Corinex has manuals for some [old equipment.](http://www.corinex.com/products/home-networking?page=shop.browse&category_id=10)  If, e.g., you've got the AV200, [this guide](http://www.corinex.com/products/home-networking?page=shop.getfile&file_id=56&product_id=21) tells you how to configure it via a web browser.

Comment: oldest version. It is actually "Corinex Powerline Ethernet Wall Mount". It predates the AV200.